# Variable scoping when reassigning/changing global variable

Tags: python, scope

I'm running into behavior in python which I'm sure is easily explained but still peculiar to me. I can run a function that attempts to "change" a global variable but does not succeed because the variable created is local:

```
x = 'n'

def make_up(letter):
    return letter.upper()


print x
>>> 'n'
print make_up(x)
>>> 'N'
print x
>>> 'n'
```

However, if I run a function where I modify a list that is accessed from the global scope, the global variable is changed:

```
x = [0,1]

def rem(lst):
   return lst.pop(0)

print x
>>> [0,1]
print rem(x)
>>> 0
print x
>>> [1]
```

What is the explanation for this behavior? In other words: why am I able to modify a list from the global scope, but the string modified locally is left untouched in the global scope?

Answer (score 0):

Here variable scope is not involved. Strings are immutable in Python. So, when you say

```
letter.upper()
```

a new string is created with uppercase letters and that is returned. Whereas in the second case, the lists are mutable. `lst` is a reference to the list which is passed and so `pop` affects the actual list.